# Polymorphism: request behaviour consistently without knowing the full class of the object

Tags: polymorphism

I am trying to understand the concept of Polymorphism. I can't understand the following sentence:

> we can request behaviour consistently without knowing the full class of the object

The book shows an example code showing three classes and then creates a reference of superclass and then use the reference to invoke derive class methods which is a usual technique for implementing polymorphism as shown below:

```
class B extends A{
void callme(){
System.out.println(“Inside B’s callme method”);
  }
}  //Q. What can you say about callme( )?
class C extends A {
void callme(){
System.out.println(“Inside C’s callme method”);
  }
}
class Dispatch {
public static void main(String args[ ]) {   
A a = new A(); //obj of Type A
B b = new B(); //obj of Type B
C c  = new C(); //obj of Type C
A r;
r = a; // r refers to an A object
r.callme();

r = b;//r refers to a B object
r.callme();  
r = c;// r refers to a C object
r.callme();
  }
}
```

Some body please guide me "Why are we saying we don't have information about the full class of object"? Constructor can tell us about the class. Also all the classes are listed here. What can be a real scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Let's have an example where the generic class names A, B and C are something a bit more 'real':

```
public class Dispatcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        Animal b = new Dog();
        Animal c = new Cat();

        a.makeSound(); // prints "Generic animal sound"
        b.makeSound(); // prints "Woof!"
        c.makeSound(); // prints "Meow~~"

        //b.chaseBall() wouldn't work
        //c.purr() wouldn't work
    }


    static class Animal {
        public void makeSound() {
            System.out.println("Generic animal sound");
        }
    }

    static class Dog extends Animal {
        @Override
        public void makeSound() {
            System.out.println("Woof!");
        }

        public void chaseBall() {
            System.out.println("*goes chasing the ball*");
        }
    }

    static class Cat extends Animal {
        @Override
        public void makeSound() {
            System.out.println("Meow~~");
        }

        public void purr() {
            System.out.println("purrrrrr");
        }
    }
}
```

In the first lines of the main method, three variables are declared, all of them of type Animal, although the second one is actually of type Dog, and the third one of type Cat. But since they are now declared as type Animal, this all the information known: that they are animals.

This is why calling makeSound() on all of these objects works: we can request behaviour (of an Animal) consistently without knowing the full class (like Dog or Cat) of the object.

But since b (a Dog) and c (a Cat) are now declared as animals, they can't have methods called corresponding to these types (like chaseBall() and purr()).